# module import work with react in dev but not in build

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to have the same module working with both Node.js and React. This works fine until I try to create a build application with React.

Here is what I am doing

```
var DummyTest = function DummyTest(){
  this.hello=function(){
    console.log("Hello Dummy Test");
  }
}

module.exports = DummyTest;
```

In Node.js:

```
const DummyTest = require("./src/utils/dummy")

var test = new DummyTest();
test.hello();
```

In React:

```
import {DummyTest} from './utils/dummy';
var test = new DummyTest();
test.hello();
```

Perfect, works both on Web and Node.js.
But if I try to create a build environment:

```
 Attempted import error: 'DummyTest' is not exported from './utils/dummy'.
```

export default can not be used because it must works also on Node.js .

Comment: Try `import * as DummyTest from './utils/dummy` or straight up requiring it in the React component's module just like you'd do in Node.

Comment: Correct, obvious answer, thanks a lot @cubrr

Comment: Oh great! Let me add that as answer. I didn't have the opportunity to test it so I posted a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
import * as DummyTest from './utils/dummy
```

...or depending on your bundler's configuration, just require it like you would in Node.

Comment: I was a little too fast: now the compilation works well, but during execution with the compiled version I have a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>`

Comment: Hmm, shame. You could use [`@babel/runtime`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-runtime) with `useESModules: true` and use `import` and `export` also in your Node code.